# Change elementary os hostname?

Tags: hostname, elementary-os

How do I change my hostname in Elementary OS?

I've tried `vi /etc/host`
didn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

For temporary change, you can use `hostname` command:

```
hostname <new name>
```

For permanent change, you must edit `/etc/hostname` file, replace old name with new name.